How to port "com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService" to Google Health?
After deprecation of Google Fit APIs i'm wondering how to port a "com.google.android.gms.fitness.service.FitnessSensorService" to Google Health?
My use case is a third party BLE device providing some fitness/health related data.
Migration Guide is no help here.

You would have to access the Sensors API on your client Android API and collate the sensor data. By then, you should be able to upload it to Google Health on whatever configuration you have setup for your platform.
